# In PHP, for what reasons can I not include a variable from external file?

Tags: php

If I have $var defined in Page1.php and in Page2.php I have

```
//Page2.php
include('Page1.php');

echo $var;
```

For what reasons will it not print the value of $var to the screen?  The files are in the same directory so paths shouldn't be the issue.   I've checked the php.ini file and nothing really jumps out at me.  Any ideas?

Comment: ...I'm assuming you've checked that $var actually has content in it? I can't count the number of times that I've accidently had white space or "" in a string and tried to print it out.

Comment: Where is the include call coming from in Page2? How is var being declared?

Comment: Steve, yes, I've checked that $var has content.  
Paolo, $var is being declared in Page1.  $var = "hello";

Comment: It'd be helpful to see Page1.php as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were a path problem you would see a warning in your error log. You could also change to require instead of include and it would become obvious.

```
echo getcwd();
```

You can also print your working directory to figure out what's wrong.

Is $var created in a function? If so, make sure you have

```
global $var;
```

before the first assignment in that function.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes:

- The current working path isn't always the same as the file's. For example, if Page2.php is being included at a higher level, that higher level will be the path. Either make sure you've loaded Page2.php directly or move Page1.php accordingly.
- Make sure `$var` is really what you expect it to be. Echo it in Page1.php to confirm. (this also checks the right file is being included)
- If the source isn't really this simple, make sure you're not undefining/clearing `$var` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested:

page1.php:

```
<?php
$foo = "bar"
?>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
include('page1.php');
echo $foo;
?>
```

This works.

You might want to check your file paths. Also var_dump() is handy to check the variable output.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you not turned off the whole [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting). Maybe the include goes wrong and so the variable never is included.